# Pull Upgrade failed: Major version number is null or out of range (>= 1)

Tags: managed-package, 2gp

I am struggling to create a new `Managed Package` version which will successfully install over the existing installed version.

**Currently Installed**

```
MyApp@0.1.0-26
```

The `sfdx-project.json` config

```
"packageDirectories": [
    {
        "path": "namespace",
        "default": true,
        "package": "MyApp",
        "versionName": "ver 1.2",
        "versionNumber": "1.2.1.NEXT",
        "ancestorVersion": "0.1.0.26"
    }
],
```

Then I create a new version:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "MyApp" -k pw -w 10 --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --loglevel TRACE --codecoverage
```

Then I promote it:

```
sfdx force:package:version:promote --package "MyApp@1.2.0-1"
```

Then when I install it, I get this error message:

> ExecutionException: Major version number is null or out of range (>= 1)

In this email report:

```
Error Message: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Major version number is null or out of range (>= 1)
Date/Time of Occurrence = 16:40:16 (GMT) on Fri, Dec 11, 2020
Subscriber Org Name = MyOrgName
Subscriber Org ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Subscriber Org Status = ACTIVE
Subscriber Org Edition Label = Enterprise Edition

Package Name = MyApp
Package ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Package Namespace = namespace
Package Type = PACKAGE2

Package Version Name (From) = ver 0.1
Package Version Id (From) = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Package Version Name (To) = ver 1.2
Package Version Id (To) = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why is it so hard to create a package which will install seamlessly over an existing package version?
3. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to install a new package version by **removing** the `InstallHandler` from the `sfdx-project.json` and commenting out the `Apex` code in to check package versions:

```
global class AppInstallHandler implements InstallHandler {
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {

        if (context != null && context.previousVersion() == null) {
            // do work     
        } else {
            // do other work
        }
    }
}
```

The clue that lead me to try this was `ExecutionException`, made me wonder if the package had gotten as far as executing... and of course the first thing that runs of the `InstallHandler` and it's first line checked the package version, so was relevant to the error message:

> Major version number is null or out of range (>= 1)